# Firebase assitant showing error when select firebase from tools menu

Tags: firebase, android-ide, android-studio-3.1.3, firebase-assistant

I am having trouble getting to firebase assistant in android studio 3.1.3. Whenever I launch firebase from studio it shows an IDE error. I have tried everything. Applied plugin into gradle file but even then I am having trouble getting to firebase inside the android studio. You know what I mean. Any helpful suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: having this message about firebase service null
java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$1.next(Iterators.java:81)

Comment: Please edit your question (there's a link right under it) to include the complete stack trace. But note that it seems unlikely anyone here will be able to fix the problem, so I'd also recommend to [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).